# Update managed synonyms using SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

I can update synonyms list using the REST call

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '["angry","upset"]' "http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"
```

How to send same request using SolrJ?

Comment: as the synonyms file is part of a config...you can upload the config and reload the collection

Comment: Changing the synonyms using the API is better for me, so the curl example works for me, I just need some help how to perform same request using SolrJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like below.

```
SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection");
ContentStreamBase.StringStream contentStream = new ContentStreamBase.StringStream(jsonBody);
contentStream.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT_TYPE);
ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest(updatePath);
req.addContentStream(contentStream);
return solrClient.request(req);
```

***Note : Good Practice is send the solrClient object to the method.***